# How to avoid API level warning?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

I'm trying to make a method to download a file, but inside the method in the request, it has a call to a function that show a notification of the download. The problem is that the minimum api required for my app is API 9, and the IDE shows me an error because setNotificationVisibility is for API 11 and above.

This is my source code:

```
public void init_download(String title, String filename, String url) {
        File path = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
               .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
               .setTitle(title)
               .setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.downloading))
               .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
               .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        //Save the request id
        SharedPreferences.Editor PrefEdit = shared_pref.edit();
        PrefEdit.putLong("DOWNLOAD_ID", id);
        PrefEdit.commit();
    }
```

How can I solve this to run notifications in both versions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` to the declaration of your functioin, this is:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void init_download(String title, String filename, String url) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the warning with `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`but in lower API's your setNotificationVisibility will not work as there is no DownloadManager in support packages.

Comment: Another problem is that the notification is showed only a few miliseconds, but it doesn't persist in the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the last problem by changing the VISIBILITY of the notification:

```
public void init_download(String title, String filename, String url) {
        File path = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdirs();
        }

        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
               .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
               .setTitle(title)
               .setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.downloading))
               .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }
        else {
            request.setShowRunningNotification(true);
        }

        long id = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        //Save the request id
        SharedPreferences.Editor PrefEdit = shared_pref.edit();
        PrefEdit.putLong("DOWNLOAD_ID", id);
        PrefEdit.commit();
    }
```

This is to download a file to the Downloads directory of your android device.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` before your method. But it will be better to up min sdk version or don't use this method. If you add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")` don't forget about users that can run you app on device with 9 api.